# Upload a file using lightning:fileUpload from a `Customer Community` user license

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customer-community

I am developing a community

One of the pages use `lightning:fileUpload` component

When I try to upload a file using the Customer Community user I allways get an error: `Can't upload 'file name'`:

[image]

**Question**

Can I use the `lightning:fileUpload` component with a Customer Community user?

Or maybe there is a problem with the File object or Content?

Comment: Are you able to capture any error logs?

Comment: I cannot see any console logs in the chrome dev console and no logs at all for the user as apex debug log

Comment: And I assume that the profile has access to ContentDocument object (and related ones)?

Comment: I checked - cannot find the object to give access to, which object exactly do you mean?

Comment: Which record are you uploading on? I was able to replicate the issue. So if I used an say Account, I was able to upload the file (that meaning you can use the component on community). However when I tried it on an Opportunity, (which is not available with Customer Community) got exactly the same error. So you may like to verify to which record the file is getting uploaded to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for your original question:

> Can I use the `lightning:fileUpload` component with a Customer Community user?

The answer is - **Yes**, you can use `lightning:fileUpload` component in Communities.

As for the error you are getting, you may like to verify if you are uploading the file to the correct record or not and that if you have the right access on the object/record provided for the community user to be able to upload the file. E.g., if you are uploading a file to Opportunity in a Customer Community, you will get error exactly as you have reported.

Below screenshots are from my test community, where I was able to upload a file successfully to Contact, whereas I got exactly the same error as you reported, if I uploaded it on an Opportunity.

Successful upload
[image]

Failed to upload (when tried to upload on object not supported in the community)
[image]

Comment: Thanks @JayantDas - that is exactly my problem. this works good on other objects, but not on my opportunity  - because of the customer community license. Do you have any workaround for this problem?

Comment: If you need access to opportunities, you need to have Partner community licenses. Opportunity is not supported in customer communities. You can get more details [here.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 1):

We just recently discovered that MFA on the mobile was causing this issue. Please see this: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002iaNgQAI

Answer (score 0):

But if you still facing the same issue. Have on this useful document provided by Salesforce.
- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Can-t-upload-or-Can-t-add-1-file-to-when-uploading-a-File&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: this has nothing to do with the problem that I had - please read the question carefully

Comment: 1. Can I use the lightning:fileUpload component with a Customer Community user?                                                                                                                  Yes, you can use lightning:fileUpload component in Communities.
2. Or maybe there is a problem with the File object or Content?                                                                It may happen that there will be active validation rules under 'Salesforce Files' that is restricting you from uploading the files. So above will tell about this in detail.

Comment: you can use lightning:fileUpload with customer community, as long as you have access to the parent object of the file